# Creating dataset for network graph using data from database

Tags: php, mysql, d3.js

I get data from my database and loop through it and compare employees of one company with employees of other companies to create an array of nodes and egdes. Nodes being companies and edges being employees working for both companies.

Comparing so many variables seems to be slowing the process a lot and is really inefficient so I am looking for a better way of achieving said array/json object.

Here is how the database looks like http://imgur.com/8iVJfwW

The final json object for d3 should look like:

`{"nodes":[{"fullName":"Anglo American plc"},{"fullName":"Associated British Foods plc"},{"fullName":"ARM Holdings plc"},{"fullName":"Dixons Carphone plc"},{"fullName":"Diageo plc"},{"fullName":"Direct Line Insurance Group PLC"},{"fullName":"easyJet plc"},{"fullName":"GKN plc"},{"fullName":"Hammerson plc"},{"fullName":"International Consolidated Airlines Group, S.A."},{"fullName":"Imperial Brands PLC"},{"fullName":"intu properties plc"},{"fullName":"Intertek Group plc"},{"fullName":"ITV plc"},{"fullName":"Johnson Matthey Plc"},{"fullName":"Kingfisher plc"},{"fullName":"Lloyds Banking Group plc"},{"fullName":"Mediclinic International plc"},{"fullName":"Merlin Entertainments plc"},{"fullName":"National Grid plc"},{"fullName":"Next Plc"},{"fullName":"Provident Financial plc"},{"fullName":"Pearson plc"},{"fullName":"Reckitt Benckiser Group plc"},{"fullName":"Royal Dutch Shell plc"},{"fullName":"RELX PLC"},{"fullName":"Rio Tinto plc"},{"fullName":"RSA Insurance Group plc"},{"fullName":"SABMiller plc"},{"fullName":"J Sainsbury plc"},{"fullName":"Sky plc"},{"fullName":"Standard Life plc"},{"fullName":"SSE plc"},{"fullName":"Severn Trent Plc"},{"fullName":"Travis Perkins plc"},{"fullName":"Tesco PLC"},{"fullName":"Taylor Wimpey plc"},{"fullName":"United Utilities Group PLC"},{"fullName":"Worldpay Group plc"},{"fullName":"Whitbread PLC"}],"edges":[{"source":0,"target":12,"officers":["PARKER, Thomas, Sir"]},{"source":0,"target":19,"officers":["STEVENS, Anne"]},{"source":0,"target":47,"officers":["GROTE, Byron"]},{"source":1,"target":14,"officers":["BASON, John"]},{"source":2,"target":13,"officers":["PUSEY, Stephen"]},{"source":2,"target":51,"officers":["KENNEDY, Christopher"]},{"source":3,"target":7,"officers":["BARKER, Glyn"]},{"source":3,"target":13,"officers":["WHEWAY, Jonathan"]},{"source":4,"target":9,"officers":["REYNOLDS, Paula"]}]};`

What I am doing is executing this query:

```
SELECT 
    CD.Company_ID,
    CD.Company_Name,
    OD.Officer_Name,
    CO.Officer_Role
FROM
    Company_Details CD
INNER JOIN Company_Officer CO 
   ON CD.Company_ID = CO.Company_ID
INNER JOIN Officer_Details OD 
   ON CO.Officer_ID = OD.Officer_ID
WHERE CD.Company_Index='FTSE 100' AND 
      CO.Resigned_On='' AND
      CO.Officer_ID IN
       ( SELECT CO2.officer_id
         FROM   Company_Officer CO2
         INNER JOIN Company_Details CD2
         ON CO2.Company_ID = CD2.Company_ID
         WHERE CO2.Resigned_On='' AND CD2.Company_Index ='FTSE 100'
         GROUP  BY CO2.officer_id
         HAVING Count( DISTINCT CO2.company_id ) > 1 
       )
ORDER BY `CD`.`Company_ID` ASC;
```

Which gives me names of officers and companies, only officers that work for more than 1 company (to create edges) and only officers that have not resigned.

First I create `$nodes` by looping through the query and getting only unique companies.

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($data)){
    array_push($Officers_DB,array("name"=>$row['Officer_Name'], "company"=>$row['Company_Name'])); 
    if(!valueExists($nodes, 'fullName', $row['Company_Name'])){ //Get rid of duplicates
        array_push($nodes, array("fullName"=>$row['Company_Name']));
    }
}
```

Then I create `$edges` by comparing each company with every other company from my `$nodes` array then I check if I am not comparing the same companies after that I loop through all officers from query and compare them with all other officers from query again I check if this isn't the same officer and then I check if officer from first loop works for `$i` company and in the next loop if officer works for '$j' company so if there is a person with the same name working for 2 different companies I create edge in `$edges`.

```
$edges = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < count($nodes); $i++) {
    for ($j = $i + 1; $j < count($nodes); $j++) {
        if ($nodes[$i]['fullName'] != $nodes[$j]['fullName']) {
            foreach($Officers_DB as $Officer){
                if($Officer['company']==$nodes[$i]['fullName']){
                    foreach($Officers_DB as $Officer2){
                        if($Officer2['company']==$nodes[$j]['fullName']){
                            if($Officer['name']==$Officer2['name']){
                                array_push($edges, array("source"=>$i, "target"=>$j, "officers"=>array($Officer['name'])));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

foreach ($edges as $i => &$edge) {
    for ($j = $i + 1; $j < count($edges); $j++) {
        if ($edge['source'] == $edges[$j]['source'] && $edge['target'] == $edges[$j]['target']) {
            foreach ($edges[$j]['officers'] as $officer) {
                array_push($edge['officers'], $officer);
            }
            array_splice($edges, $j, 1);
        }
    }
}
```

This method works but is really slow and inefficient and I was wondering of other ways of achieving the same result.

Here is how the database looks like Company_details: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nSwcM.png companies are unique

Officer_details: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XU6W7.png officers are unique

and Company_Officer: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OIslI.png which is the relational table between the other two. With relation one to many and many to one.

Comment: looks like you're basically checking for array intersections, or at least duplicate names in the officers table. wouldn't it be easier to just `array_count_values()` and then deal with only the names that have counts >=2?

Comment: @MarcB I dont fully get what you are suggesting to be honest. I have added to the question 3 more screenshots of how the tables actually look like.